# Is it possible to get only the updated value with angularfire?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm using angularfire and the realtime database
I have a database as so :

```
actions:{
  uid1: {
    meta...
  },
  uid2: {
    meta...
  },
  uid3: {
    meta...
  },
  uid4: {
    meta...
  },
}
```

I've made an editor showing all of that actions. Now let say I add an action (`uid5`) my `valueChanges` method send me back all the uids when I only need the updated value.

I would do something a bit like this

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.db.object(`actions`).valueChanges().subscribe(
    (actions) => console.log(actions) // here I get first time uid1{}, uid2{} ..., uid4{}
    //second time after adding uid5 I would get uid5{} only.
  )
}
```

So is it possible, is there some specific event or whatsoever or should I make a feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase or AngularFire to get only the new items, so you'll have to built something yourself.

The two most common options:

1. Store a `timestamp` value in each node, and then query for only items after "now" with something like `ref.orderBy("timestamp").startAt(Date.now())`.
2. Start at keys after now, with something like `ref.orderByKey().startAt(ref.push().key)`.

Comment: I was looking at that but what about 'child_changed', "child_removed"... . You technic could work but would only work for added element not changed and updatde. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That actually depends what timestamp you store. For example, if you store the timestamp that the node was last modified, you can query for items about when they were modified.

Comment: true but still what about the `child_added/removed/changed` I've implement some of them and looks like it's working. What would be the difference?  ...

Comment: Listening to `child_` events makes no difference to what data is retrieved from the server. So event if you only listen to `child_changed`, your app is still retrieving all nodes under at `actions`.

Comment: So two question questions here.First. WHat you are telling me is listening to `child_*` events is even worst, imagine I have added two more childs I would grab past ones + current one two times right? Also what about deletion with timestamp method. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Listening to `value` and listening to (any or all) `child_` are the same when it comes to what goes over the wire. The reason for picking one or the other is what you want to with the data, not what data is read. For example, UI updates may be easier from `child_` handlers as those fire precisely on the level that has changed.

Comment: On deletion: you'd have to store the fact that something was deleted in the database in that case.